# How to differentiate domains using Spring RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, url, dns

I'm trying to use different methodes depending on from which domain the request is send.

e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", domain = "google.de", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleDeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", domain = "google.com", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleComRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
}
```

The two domains are routing to one, the same, server and webapp, but I'd like to return a different modelAndView in the controllerclass depending from which URL the reqeust is comming.

Any ideas?

cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not have a single `handleRequest` method where you simply check HTTP referrer header and act correspondingly - fork into different methods, etc.?